# Remove Categories / Tags From Admin Menu

Tags: posts, customization, admin-menu, sub-menu

I want to remove or hide Categories / Tags submenu under Posts in the Admin Menu. I know this works with the themes submenus:

`remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'widgets.php' );`

The same doesn't seem to work for posts unfortunately:

`remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php', 'edit-tags.php' );`

I'm using the admin_menu action: `add_action( 'admin_menu', 'function_call' )`

Do I need to add something else?

Comment: Upvote this question, you heathens!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_remove_sub_menus');

function my_remove_sub_menus() {
    remove_submenu_page('edit.php', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category');
    remove_submenu_page('edit.php', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag');
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this hide the tag and category areas in the Quick Edit section, but I do so `remove_meta_box` working as described.

Comment: This is not the prefered method, its like removeing them using css, doesn't guarantee anything. check mbacon40 answer, it looks promissing.

Comment: @jnhghy-JanteaAlexandru `remove_submenu_page` does **not** use CSS to remove the submenu, it removes the entry form the global menu array (see [source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_submenu_page/)) so the HTML markup for the menu is not rendered at all (and not CSS-hidden). However, it is true that in some cases it may not prevent users from accessing the screen for the removed submenu directly (see [ticket #18850](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18850)) but OP asked to remove the menu, and it **is** the way to go.

Comment: @gmazzap I was makning a comparation. Removing it this way will not ensure tags are not added by other means ( front end ), I was trying to point out that this removes only the menu entry and not the post type connection to the taxonomy. :)

Answer (score 12):

If you want to completely remove categories and tags you can do so like this:

```
// Remove Categories and Tags
add_action('init', 'myprefix_remove_tax');
function myprefix_remove_tax() {
    register_taxonomy('category', array());
    register_taxonomy('post_tag', array());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may also want to remove the meta boxes from the Post Creation page

```
// REMOVE POST META BOXES
function remove_my_post_metaboxes() {
  remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv','post','normal' ); // Categories Metabox
  remove_meta_box( 'tagsdiv-post_tag','post','normal' ); // Tags Metabox
}
add_action('admin_menu','remove_my_post_metaboxes');
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @mbacon40 and to @gmazzap I was able to use this to remove Product Tags and Categories (product_tag and product_cat) from my menu and from the product add/edit pages.

```
// Remove Categories and Tags
add_action('init', 'myprefix_remove_tax');
function myprefix_remove_tax() {
    register_taxonomy('product_cat', array());
    register_taxonomy('product_tag', array());
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_remove_sub_menus');
function my_remove_sub_menus() {
    remove_submenu_page('edit.php', 'edit-tags.php?    taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product');
    remove_submenu_page('edit.php', 'edit-tags.php?    taxonomy=product_tag&post_type=product');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for some reason the edit.php does not work at my setup 5.3

This however works

```
remove_submenu_page( 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=post_tag' );
remove_submenu_page( 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category' );
```