# Remove Categories and Tags from Admin Dashboard

Tags: categories, tags, dashboard

I'm using my own taxonomy for blog posts and would like to remove Categories and Tags from the Dashboard. I've removed them from the Admin Menu and the meta boxes on the Edit Posts page from this question here: [Remove Categories / Tags From Admin Menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110782/remove-categories-tags-from-admin-menu)

But now I'm trying to remove it from the All Posts page in the Dashboard where it shows a list of all the posts in a table and across the top are Title, Author, Categories, Tags, Date, etc. I can't seem to find how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like @fatwombat suggested you need to rewrite the table. If you can't modify the @Milo solution, here is a snippet that will remove the columns:

```
function my_manage_columns( $columns ) {
    unset($columns['categories'], $columns['tags']);
    return $columns;
}

function my_column_init() {
    add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns' , 'my_manage_columns' );
}

add_action( 'admin_init' , 'my_column_init' );
```

Answer (score 1):

That actually requires you to rewrite the table itself.

The following link can help you with this:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19182/81482